# Creating column and value from Multivalue field with : sep delimit

Tags: python, pandas

```
data ={'Incident':['Inc12344','Inc434324','Inc435435'],
'template':['inboundq','outboundq','store'],
'Description':['accno(s): 2852/nChannel: Inbound/nError:cant login','accno(s): 4435/nChannel: outbound/nError:cant register/ncomments:retry','accno(s): 56456/nChannel: store/nError:cant enroll/ncomments:retry/ndetails:retry failed']
```

Above is sample data in in csv file.Description columns contains /n separted strings that represent fields:values seperated by ':' what's the best approach to seperate these to columns/values

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: columns and rows. Something like Incident,template,accno(s),channel,error,comments,details with values in rows.

Answer (score 2):

You can read your data in a dataframe, split the `Description` twice (first on `/n`, then on `:`) using `explode` to create rows from the first split and then `expand` to create columns from the second, then `pivot` the df to your desired result:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['Description'] = df['Description'].str.split('/n')
df = df.explode('Description')
df[['Description', 'value']] = df['Description'].str.split(r':\s*', expand=True)
out = (df
    .pivot(index=['Incident','template'], columns='Description', values='value')
    .reset_index()
)
out.columns.name = ''
```

Output for your sample data:

```
      Incident   template   Channel          Error accno(s) comments       details
0     Inc12344   inboundq   Inbound     cant login     2852      NaN           NaN
1    Inc434324  outboundq  outbound  cant register     4435    retry           NaN
2    Inc435435      store     store    cant enroll    56456    retry  retry failed
```

Comment: Very crisp approach. What does `out.columns.name = ''` do?

Comment: @rajkumar_data when you pivot the column index gets named according to the `columns` parameter. `out.columns.name = ''` resets that to an empty string. Try running the code up to that point and you'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

Split Description by `/n` to get `column_name:value` pairs and obtain column names. Using a separate function, extract corresponding values for a given column name.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
# new column names are not consistent in every row
# get all possible new column names
new_cols_all = df.Description.map(lambda row: {val.split(':')[0] for val in row.split('/n')})

# get unique set of column names
new_cols_set = set()
for row_entry in new_cols_all:
    new_cols_set.update(row_entry)

# a function to get value given column name
def get_value1(text, col_name):
    text = [val.split(':') for val in text.split('/n')]
    # assumes the input format is fixed to be col_name:value
    # otherwise write following in a try-except statement
    for key,value in text:
        if key==col_name:
            return value

# create new columns in dataframe
for col_name in new_cols_set:
    df[col_name] = df.Description.apply(get_value, args=(col_name,))

# drop Description column if not required
df.drop(columns=['Description'],inplace=True)
```

Final output would be:

```
    Incident    template    comments    Error           accno(s)    details         Channel
0   Inc12344    inboundq    None        cant login      2852        None            Inbound
1   Inc434324   outboundq   retry       cant register   4435        None            outbound
2   Inc435435   store       retry       cant enroll     56456       retry failed    store
```